# Definite integral with $\mbox{}_{2}\mathrm{F}_{1}$ hypergeometric function

Tags: integration

I would like to evaluate double integral $$\int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_0^v \frac{u^h}{1-u^h}(1-v)\frac{v^{h-1}}{1-v^h} du dv.$$
I can evaluate the inner integral $$\int\limits_0^v \frac{u^h}{1-u^h} du = \frac{v^{h+1}}{h+1}\cdot\mbox{}_{2}\mathrm{F}_{1} (1, \frac{1}{h}+1; \frac{1}{h}+2; v^h)$$ using Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's table of integrals, but I am not able to manage to evaluate integral $$\int\limits_0^1 v^{2h}(1-v)\frac{1}{1-v^h}\cdot\mbox{}_{2}\mathrm{F}_{1} (1, \frac{1}{h}+1; \frac{1}{h}+2; v^h) dv.$$ Could anyone help me please? Thank you.